# How to disable CD-ROM/DVD-ROM polling during boot in Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, optical-drive

I have a Dell XPS L501X laptop dual-booting Linux Mint 12 "Lisa" (x64) and Windows 7. It has a TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-L633J DVD drive, which generates a lot of vibrations and noise whenever data is being read through it.

While booting into Linux, somehow the DVD drive is polled/accessed thereby creating a nuisance. Now, I can think of several ways to disable this drive once Linux is booted, but I need some way to disable it *during* the boot.

Following are the approaches that I have tried (and failed):

1. `hal-disable-polling`: This command stops polling once Linux is booted.
2. `cdrom.ko`: Came across this in many [blog posts](http://www.tejasbarot.com/2010/05/07/disable-block-cddvd-rom-linux-rhel), but I simply could not find this file at the mentioned location.
3. BIOS: My laptop's BIOS hasn't got any option to disable the DVD drive.

What else can I do to disable the DVD drive?

I am using Linux Kernel 3.0.0-26-generic. Windows 7 boots just fine.

Comment: I had a related problem (though during normal usage, not during boot), and it turned out `udisks` resp. `udisks2` was the culprit. I fought it for some time, and finally settled on modifying the `udev` rules (so `udisks` is never invoked). That *may* also work during boot, if you make sure the modified `udev` rules end up in the boot image. Though if the access is due to a device reset during boot, that won't help.

Comment: Have you tried blacklisting kernel module (cdrom.ko) using blacklist or kernel boot option (`modprobe.blacklist=cdrom`)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve that issue would be by changing the boot order so the system attempts to boot from the hard drive before the DVD drive.  However, it'd also mean if you wanted to boot from the DVD down the road, you'd have to switch the boot order back to the way it was originally.

This explains the process of changing the boot sequence in BIOS.  While not directly targeted at your model, it's close enough.

Link: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/635319/Dell-Xps-13.html?page=57